# Auto Layout constraints for container view inside UITableView header broken for different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have an issue that makes no sense to me. I have the following setup:

| UITableView |

|| UITableView header ||

||| UIView |||

So inside my UITableView header I have a container view that has leading, trailing and top constraints to its superview. Everything is set up correctly for my test device size (which is iPhone 8). If I change the test device to iPhone 8 Plus I get a strange offset for my trailing constraint - 39pt to the right edge, which is exactly the difference between iPhone 8 plus width in points and iPhone 8.

When I switch between devices in Xcode and see that the trailing constraint is not correct I just make an adjustment myself (change trailing to 1 and then back to 0) and the problem goes away for the particular device.

Initially I thought it is bug in Xcode but when I tested on a device the problem is still there.

I tried setting up a new view controller and adding the same elements but with no effect.

I am attaching screenshots to make my issue clearer.

**Before**: Adjusting the desired constraints

[image: Using the desired trailing constraint in iPhone 8 size]

**After**: Switching to a device with different size

[image: Trailing constraint is broken for all other device sizes]

Comment: Expand **all** of the `>` in the document pane (so we can see all the subviews and constraints) and re-post your screen-caps.

Comment: OK - rather difficult to tell what all is going on... I'd suggest you start fresh, and add your first element. Make sure it sizes correctly. Add a second element, check the result. And so on. Tip: give your views / labels / etc contrasting background colors to make it easier to see the framing.

Comment: I actually just opened a new project and set up the same hierarchy - UITableView with header view with child container view. The result is the same. So I guess it has to do with this kind of setup. Still makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you post the source for your storyboard, I'll take a quick look.

Comment: Do you want me to share the example project? It's just a view controller with a table view that fills the whole vc. Then I add a UIView as a table view header and another UIView that has leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints attached to header's edges. When you change devices you can see the problem.

Comment: Sure - share the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I accepted DonMag's answer (thanks for your time) as this really seemed to be an Xcode Interface Builder bug. As I investigated further when having the scenario I mentioned auto layout constraints are not updating the layout when I need it hence not giving me the right `view.bounds`.

I tried getting it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` without success as well - it was still giving me a size that suits another device.

What did the trick was calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` before working with view's bounds. What it does is to update the view's layout immediately. As a result you can access the desired view's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as an answer because it's too much for a comment - even though it's really just a confirmation, not a solution.

OK - looked at your project.

I'd say it's an IB / Storyboard bug, which I've seen in other circumstances. If you change the `View As...` device, the frame does not update immediately.

However, if you change anything that would cause a layout update - such as temporarily changing the background color of a view or font size of a label - everything should snap into place.

You'll also notice that if you select an element and move it slightly, the `Update Frames` button / menu item becomes enabled... and that will also correctly update the frames.

**Note:** When I ran the app, regardless of how the layout looked in Storyboard, the constraints correctly sized the views at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Exactly, I experienced the same behavior. But when I change the device from the menu it bugs again. Also I wouldn't really care if this only happened in the storyboard but this happens in my live app on the app store.

Comment: Now downloading Xcode 11 and hope this goes away because I am out of ideas.

Comment: If it's happening at run-time, then it sounds like something else is going on - because I don't experience it with that simple example.

Comment: Yes, sorry for misleading you. It is also an IB bug here in the test project when I run it. So once again I will do what you've also recommended - create a new view controller and add the elements one by one. Will let you know how it goes. Cheers.